# Drilling down on reputation by post doesn't work for documentation-based rep changes

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation-history

See below for an example when the reputation tab is set to `post`. Not sure if it's all the time or just when it's possible to drill down but it's not showing the 2 rep. events that happened for that post on that day.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see this has now been fixed.